# How to remove connected objects in binary image using ConnectedComponents

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I am using EmguCV and C#. I want to remove small connected objects from my image using ConnectedComponentsWithStats

[I have following binary image as input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPFGJ.jpg)

I am able to draw a rectangle for specified area. Now i want to remove objects from binary image

Here is my code

```
Image<Gray, byte> imgry = image.Convert<Gray, byte>();
    var mask = imgry.InRange(new Gray(50), new Gray(255));

    var label = new Mat();
    var stats = new Mat();
    var centroids = new Mat();
    int labels = CvInvoke.ConnectedComponentsWithStats(mask, label, stats,
                                                       centroids,
                                                       LineType.EightConnected,
                                                       DepthType.Cv32S);

    var img = stats.ToImage<Gray, int>();

    Image<Gray, byte> imgout1 = new Image<Gray, byte>(image.Width, image.Height);

    for (var i = 1; i < labels; i++)
    {
        var area = img[i, (int)ConnectecComponentsTypes.Area].Intensity;
        var width = img[i, (int)ConnectecComponentsTypes.Width].Intensity;
        var height = img[i, (int)ConnectecComponentsTypes.Height].Intensity;    
        var top = img[i, (int)ConnectecComponentsTypes.Top].Intensity;
        var left = img[i, (int)ConnectecComponentsTypes.Left].Intensity;

        var roi = new Rectangle((int)left, (int)top, (int)width, (int)height);

        if (area > 1000)
        {
            CvInvoke.Rectangle(imgout1, roi, new MCvScalar(255), 1);

        }
    }
```

[Drawn Rectangle for specified area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4M0j.jpg)

How can i remove objects of specified size

[My output image should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agfta.jpg)

I have achieved one way by using contours it works fine for small image, when i have large image 10240*10240 and more number of particles my application entering to break mode

Comment: you can use morphological operations like erosion to remove small objects

Comment: Thanks @user8190410 when i apply morphological operation to remove small objects it will affect the larger objects by modifying its original shape. If in case i want to remove "large objects" of specific size from binary image by remaining small objects in it, how we will achieve this.

Comment: use morphological opening/closing and an ellipse structuring element. Another approach could be find contours in image; create a new image, check if contour area is greater than a threshold then draw it on new image

Comment: I have achieved one way by using contours it works fine for small image, when i have large image 10240*10240 and more number of particles, my application entering to break mode. I have to process on larger image and processing speed should not be more than few miliseconds

Comment: you can down sample image for that purpose

Comment: Using contours is not the way to go—you don’t want to process one object at a time. You are looking for an operation called area opening. I don’t know if EmguCV has this or not, but look for a library that does.